# Python print statement using f strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I came across a print statement with f strings which was as below:

```
a = "data"
print(f">{a:^10}<")
```

The output that i get out of this is as below:

```
>   data   <
```

What i would like to understand is the **^10** in the above print statement.
Can someone explain?

Comment: Why not read the documentation?

Comment: See if this documentation helps you https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` is for center aligned, and `10` means the minimum width.

You can check the format string syntax [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).